# Calculate Inactive User on Specific Week (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

[image: example table]

and I want to calculate active and dormant users for each week.

expected result:

```
     week        |      Highly Active    |   Medium Active  |   Ligthly Active  |   dormant
===============================================================================================
 15 Mar 21       |         ...           |        ...       |        ...        |     ...
 22 Mar 21       |         ...           |        ...       |        ...        |     ...
 29 Mar 21       |         ...           |        ...       |        ...        |     ...
 05 Apr 21       |         ...           |        ...       |        ...        |     ...
```

Highly active (>= 3 activity / week) --> query done.

Medium active (= 2 activity / week) --> query done.

Lightly active (= 1 activity / week) --> query done.

Dormant (user that not active on specific week. example based on table image: User "En" is being dormant on week 22 Mar 21 because his last activity was on week 15 Mar 21).

my query is:

```
    SELECT week,
           count(distinct uid) filter (where activity >= 3 and last_seen >= week) as highly_active,
           count(distinct uid) filter (where activity = 2 and last_seen >= week) as medium_active,
           count(distinct uid) filter (where activity = 1 and last_seen >= week) as light_active,
           count(distinct uid) filter (where last_seen < week) as dormant
    FROM
    (....
```

but the dormant in every week shows 0.
is there any effective way to calculate dormant user in this case? any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you'll not see any data for `dormant` accounts on a precise week thus the `0`.

Usually the dormant calculation, or any calculation for which the dataset is empty for a particular period, is created with a cross join between a `WEEK` and the `ACCOUNTS` tables  to get a row for each `account` and `week` in the dataset.

Create a table listing all the weeks

```
create table week (week_id int, week_starting_date date);

insert into week select 3, TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD');
insert into week select 4, TO_DATE('20210322','YYYYMMDD');
```

Create a table with activity data

```
create table activity (week_starting_date date, full_name varchar, activity int, last_seen date);

insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210322','YYYYMMDD'), 'Andrea', 8, TO_DATE('20210325','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210322','YYYYMMDD'), 'Fausto', 2, TO_DATE('20210323','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210322','YYYYMMDD'), 'Carlo', 5, TO_DATE('20210322','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210322','YYYYMMDD'), 'Sergio', 12, TO_DATE('20210324','YYYYMMDD');


insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD'), 'Andrea', 8, TO_DATE('20210320','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD'), 'Fausto', 2, TO_DATE('20210316','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD'), 'Carlo', 5, TO_DATE('20210318','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD'), 'Sergio', 12, TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD');
insert into activity select TO_DATE('20210315','YYYYMMDD'), 'Ugo', 6, TO_DATE('20210317','YYYYMMDD');
```

Create a table listing all the accounts

```
create table account (full_name varchar);
insert into account values ('Andrea');
insert into account values ('Fausto');
insert into account values ('Carlo');
insert into account values ('Sergio');
insert into account values ('Ugo');
```

As you can see below, `Ugo` will be the example of `dormant` account, not showing data for your week `2021-03-22`.

```
defaultdb=> select * from activity order by week_starting_date desc, full_name;
 week_starting_date | full_name | activity | last_seen  
--------------------+-----------+----------+------------
 2021-03-22         | Andrea    |        8 | 2021-03-25
 2021-03-22         | Carlo     |        5 | 2021-03-22
 2021-03-22         | Fausto    |        2 | 2021-03-23
 2021-03-22         | Sergio    |       12 | 2021-03-24
 2021-03-15         | Andrea    |        8 | 2021-03-20
 2021-03-15         | Carlo     |        5 | 2021-03-18
 2021-03-15         | Fausto    |        2 | 2021-03-16
 2021-03-15         | Sergio    |       12 | 2021-03-15
 2021-03-15         | Ugo       |        6 | 2021-03-17
(9 rows)
```

If we now create a **cross-join** between `account` and `week` we can see that there are `10` rows, instead of the above `9`. The extra row includes the entry for `Ugo` in week `2021-03-22`.

```
defaultdb=> select * from week cross join account order by week_starting_date desc, full_name;
 week_id | week_starting_date | full_name 
---------+--------------------+-----------
       4 | 2021-03-22         | Andrea
       4 | 2021-03-22         | Carlo
       4 | 2021-03-22         | Fausto
       4 | 2021-03-22         | Sergio
       4 | 2021-03-22         | Ugo
       3 | 2021-03-15         | Andrea
       3 | 2021-03-15         | Carlo
       3 | 2021-03-15         | Fausto
       3 | 2021-03-15         | Sergio
       3 | 2021-03-15         | Ugo
(10 rows)
```

now we can use this, to **left outer join** with the `activity` table and get the correct results.

```
with all_options as 
(select week_starting_date, full_name from week cross join account)
select all_options.week_starting_date,
sum(case when activity.activity >= 3 then 1 end) highly_active,
sum(case when activity.activity = 2 then 1 end) medium_active,
sum(case when activity.activity = 1 then 1 end) lightly_active,
sum(case when activity.activity is null then 1 end) dormant
 from all_options left outer join activity on all_options.week_starting_date = activity.week_starting_date and
all_options.full_name = activity.full_name
group by all_options.week_starting_date;
```

With the result being

```
 week_starting_date | highly_active | medium_active | lightly_active | dormant 
--------------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------
 2021-03-22         |             3 |             1 |                |       1
 2021-03-15         |             4 |             1 |                |       0
```

an alternative is just to count the available `accounts` and to define `dormant` as the total number of accounts less the ones with activity like in the below.

```
with all_accounts as (
select count(*) total_accounts from account
),
activity_summary as (
select week_starting_date,
sum(case when activity.activity >= 3 then 1 end) highly_active,
sum(case when activity.activity = 2 then 1 end) medium_active,
sum(case when activity.activity = 1 then 1 end) lightly_active,
count(*) as total_active
from activity
group by week_starting_date)
select week_starting_date,
highly_active,
medium_active,
lightly_active,
total_accounts-total_active as dormant
from activity_summary cross join all_accounts;
```